# How can I get from one factored form to another?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, factoring

This came from trying to factor $x^6 + 1$. We know that

$x^4 - x^2 + 1 =  (x^4 +2 x^2 + 1) -3x^2 = (x^2+1)^2 - 3x^2 = (x^2 - \sqrt 3 x + 1)(x^2 + \sqrt 3 x + 1)$

I expected that if I factored the $x^4 - x^2 + 1$ completely into $4$ factors and then regrouped them $2$ by $2$, I could arrive at $(x^2 - \sqrt 3 x + 1)(x^2 + \sqrt 3 x + 1)$

$$\left(x+ \sqrt {\dfrac {1 + \sqrt 3 i}{2}}\right) \left(x+ \sqrt {\dfrac {1 - \sqrt 3 i}{2}}\right) \left(x- \sqrt {\dfrac {1 + \sqrt 3 i}{2}}\right) \left(x- \sqrt {\dfrac {1 - \sqrt 3 i}{2}}\right)$$

But that didn't happen. No matter how I group them into quadratics, I always end up with a complex coefficient. How can I get $(x^2 - \sqrt 3 x + 1)(x^2 + \sqrt 3 x + 1)$ from the $4$ factors?

Comment: Group 1 and 3, 2 and 4. But you notation is not precise enough: the notation $\sqrt{\;}$ is meaning less for a non-real number.

Comment: Yes, this is the reason why I took my first comment off, as Bernard indicates, actually having a complex term inside a square root is pretty meaningless as the outcome of such a root is not unique. For example, what is the exact outcome of $\sqrt{i}$ if I assume that the square root operation should give me one answer? Your notation is well meant, but ambiguous

Comment: @Bernard But $$\left(x+ \sqrt {\dfrac {1 + \sqrt 3 i}{2}}\right) \left(x- \sqrt {\dfrac {1 + \sqrt 3 i}{2}}\right)  = \left( x^2 - \left( \sqrt {\dfrac {1 + \sqrt 3 i}{2}} \right) ^2 \right) =  \left( x^2 -   \dfrac {1 + \sqrt 3 i}{2} \right)$$

Comment: @Bernard What would be a good way to represent these roots then witouth the $\sqrt {}$ notation? I got these roots by using the quadratic formula on $x^4 - x^2 + 1$ to get $x^2 =   \dfrac {1 \pm \sqrt 3 i}{2} $ and then took the square root of each side. How should I have decomposed it into $4$ factors otherwise?

Comment: @imranfat Please see the above comments. A similar issue happens when I try multiplying the $1^{st}$ and $4^{th}$ factors as well

Comment: Yes, but the problem remains, what answer do you assign to something like $\sqrt{i}$? The equation $x^2=i$ has two solutions, being $\sqrt{0.5}+\sqrt{0.5}i$ and $-(\sqrt{0.5}+\sqrt{0.5}i)$ Which one do you pick in your factors. That's what is messing up the algebra

Comment: This is linked to $\mathbf C$ having no order compatible with the field structure. I would calculate explicitly the square roots. It's not hard.

Comment: @Ovi: In the present case, there's no problem. In more complex (no pun) situations, you may have ambiguities to know who is who, which may lead to apparent contradictions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}\pm i}{2}\right)^2 = \frac{3-1\pm 2\sqrt{3}i}{4} = \frac{1\pm\sqrt{3}i}{2} \implies \underbrace{\sqrt{\frac{1\pm \sqrt{3}i}{2}} = \frac{\sqrt{3}\pm i}{2}}_{\text{assume taking principal branch of } \sqrt{\;}}
\\
{\Huge\Downarrow}
\\
\left(x \pm \sqrt{\frac{1 + \sqrt{3}i}{2}}\right)
\left(x \pm \sqrt{\frac{1 - \sqrt{3}i}{2}}\right)\\
\| \\
x^2 \pm \left(\frac{\sqrt{3} + i}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{3} - i}{2}\right) +
\left(\frac{\sqrt{3} + i}{2}\right)\left(\frac{\sqrt{3} - i}{2}\right)\\
\| \\
x^2 \pm \sqrt{3}x + 1
$$

Answer (score 2):

Solve the equation
$$
x^6=-1
$$
using polar coordinates: $-1=e^{\pi i}$, so
$$
x_k=e^{\frac{\pi+2\pi k}{6}i}=e^{\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{6}i},
$$
for $k\in\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$. Therefore 
$$
\begin{split}
x^6+1 &=\prod_{k=0}^{5}\left(x-e^{\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{6}i}\right)\\
&=\textstyle(x-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}-\frac{1}{2}i)(x-i)(x+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}-\frac{1}{2}i)
(x+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}+\frac{1}{2}i)(x+i)(x-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}+\frac{1}{2}i)
\end{split}
$$